# $211!$ or $106^{211}$:Which is greater?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, factorial, number-comparison

A BdMO question:

> Let $a=211!$ and $b=106^{211}$. Show which is greater with proper logic.

By matching term by term,it is pretty easy to note that

$106!<106^{106}$

$106^{105}<107\cdot 108\cdot 109...........211$

However I am at a loss to see how this will help.The solution must something along the lines of this one but I am unable to see so.I also factorized 106 but it complicated matters further.A hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a trick similar to Gauss' famous trick for summation (although he probably wasn't the first, if at all, to discover it).

Divide the $211!$ into pairs, $(1,211),(2,210),(3,209),\ldots(105,107)$. Now we can note that for every such pair can be written as $(106-k,106+k)$ and therefore: $$(106-k)(106+k)=106^2-k^2<106^2.$$

Now it's easy to finish. There are $105$ pairs and one additional $106$ to each side. Therefore $211!<106^{211}$.

Comment: "...the first, if at all"?

Comment: @Tonky: There are doubts that the story about him discovering that in age seven or so, and the formula was probably known before him.

Comment: Ah. I thought you were speculating that perhaps there _was_ no first person to discover it. My bad.

Comment: I was wondering,is there a way to generalize this so that whenever we have $x!$ and $y^x$ we can say immediately which one is greater.

Comment: @Tony: There might not have been a first one. Perhaps the dinosaurs figured it out and left it carved on the ages, so when hominids began scouring the earth they have learned about this formula, and so it was passed from father to son, for generations and aeons, long before men appeared to begin with!!

Comment: @rah4927: Probably not, but if there's anything to generalize I *guess* that if $x<2y$ then the above argument should work just fine (clearly we can immediate start with $x=2y-1$ which is the maximal value possible for this).

Comment: @AsafKaragila  . Stirling's series for log n!

Answer (score 15):

Apply GM $\le$ AM to $1,\ldots,211$, we have

$$211! \le \left[\frac{1}{211}\left(1 + \ldots + 211\right)\right]^{211} = 106^{211}$$

Since the list $1,\ldots,211$ is not a constant list, the above inequality is strict. i.e.
$$211! < 106^{211}$$

Comment: Ha ha!That's a brilliant one as well.Well done.+1 from me.

Answer (score 11):

$1\cdot 211<106\cdot106$

$2\cdot210<106\cdot106$

$...$

$105\cdot107<106\cdot106$

So clearly $211! < 106^{211}$

Comment: Ha!That was a neat answer.

Comment: It should be noted that there's no real reason why it's *completely* obvious why the $\ldots$ part is true.

Comment: Your answer complements this one nicely,then.

Comment: @rah4927: I'm just happy I managed to solve it in under five minutes. I'm not the one for dealing with actual numbers. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Just look at $211!=(106-105)(106-104)...(106-1)106(106+1)...(106+104)(106+105)$ then compare $106^2$ and $(106+n)(106-n)$ when $1\le n \le 105$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), $n!\simeq\bigg(\!\!\dfrac ne\!\!\bigg)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$.

Comment: Okay,I should have seen Stirling's formula coming.I should have mentioned that this problem came in the Junior Section of the Nationals and therefore the students probably don't know anything about Stirling approximation.

Comment: And the Striling's formula as you stated (and as most of us remember, I think) does not contain any bounds or error estimation, so it's not usable for exact inequalities. The bounds in the preface of the Wikipedia page may work in this case, I didn't check.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be "simplified" by taking logarithms of both numbers. Then:

$$\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{211}\log(k)}{211\log(106)}<\frac{922}{984}<1.$$

This implies $$\sum_{k=2}^{211}\log(k)<211\log(106),$$

or in other words

$$211!<106^{211}.$$

EDIT: This still leaves the problem of working out the logarithms in the first inequality. There may be a nice way of proving the first inequality.

Comment: Clever, but how would you calculate the sum of logarithms, and $\log(106)$ by hand?

Answer (score 1):

You have received very good answers to your post. But, let me go further and suppose  the problem to be : find the smallest value of $x$ such that  $$211! < x^{211}$$  Using, as suggested by Lucian, Stirling's approximation of $n!$ and taking logarithms of both sides immediately leads to $921.837 < 211 \space \log(x)$ that is to say $x >78.9564$. So, the answer is 79.